# How to add a new repo/page to my GitHub hosted website?

Tags: github, github-pages

I currently have a website hosted on `myUserName.github.io`. I found out that I can add a new page to it by pushing another repository to its gh-pages branch, but I am not sure how to do this exactly since I am dealing with two different repositories.

If I have a repository named "test", how do I add this my website so I have `myUserName.github.io/test`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want. [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) explicitly hosts websites based on [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) and is unable to help you in hosting any other kind of backend. If you want to have a website for other purposes and not built out of Jekyll, you need to find somewhere else.

If you just want to add a new page via Jekyll, see their [Guides](https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/)